# Passing arguments to nested to_json call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Consider a controller action that returns the following:

```
Post.includes(:comments).to_json(:include => [:comments])
```

Is it somehow possible to pass arguments to the `to_json` comments method call so that I could modify comments json representation in this place rather than doing it in `Comment` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`to_json` only accepts a list of options, [per the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)...  If you absolutely had to, you could monkey-patch `to_json` to do whatever work you needed to do, then call `super` to execute the default `to_json`, but I wouldn't recommend this.

In your situation, based on what I understand you're describing, it's probably best to simply do it either on the `Comment` model, or as a private method on the controller.

Comment: Thank you for that reference. I just noticed that the last example  (2nd level and higher order associations) is exactly what I was looking for!